Primefaces fileUpload - not able to capture the file/event
I'm trying to upload a file using PrimeFaces, but the fileUploadListener method isn't being invoked after the upload finishes.
view:
            <p:layoutUnit position="east" header="#{resourceBundle['bulk.upload.heading']}" resizable="true" size="300">
                <h:form id="bulk-upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <p:fileUpload mode="simple" auto="false" value="#{productTreeDisplay.uploadedFile}" fileUploadListener="#{productTreeDisplay.importFile}"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{productTreeDisplay.importFile}" ajax="false"/>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>

Java class:
    private transient UploadedFile uploadedFile;

    public UploadedFile getFile() {return uploadedFile;};

    public void setFile (UploadedFile uploadedFile) {this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;};

    public void importFile(FileUploadEvent event) {
        UploadedFile uploadedFile = event.getFile();
        String fileName = uploadedFile.getFileName();
        String contentType = uploadedFile.getContentType();
        byte[] contents = uploadedFile.getContents(); // Or getInputStream()
        // ... Save it, now!
    }

web.xml:
    <!-- File upload params-->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
        <param-value>auto</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

I know that the java class is instantiated and also connected to view. I can hit various breakpoints in the java class.
Primefaces: 4.0 version
jsf-impl: 2.2.8-01
Java: 8
Just in case, I have added also commons-fileupload:1.31.1 and commons-io:2.2
When I debug the java class and I upload the file, the application does not hit the breakpoint. The server returns 200 OK but I am not able to access the file that is being uploaded

Unfortunately you are using very old versions of all of those libraries so it will be hard to get much help.  I use FileUpload in over 70 projects without issue but I stay on top of my PrimeFaces upgrades.
